# ColdFusion 9 : Mathematical Query

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a table containing content numbers. I want to add the value from each row of the table:

```
table name: item
columns:    item_name, item_price.
```

How can I sum up the values in the `item_price` column?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) . The reason for asking is that this is a very basic question that could be answered with a quick search. (In fact your own post contains the answer). Though I did not down-vote it, questions that do not demonstrate any effort tend to be down-voted a lot. However, it is also possible your question is more complex than it appears. But since we do not what you have tried, it is hard to tell the difference.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what database you are using, but the syntax would look similar to:

```
SELECT SUM( item_price) FROM item
```

Answer (score 2):

with CF, here we go

```
<cfset TotalItemPrice = 0>
<cfoutput query="myQrt">
    <cfset TotalItemPrice = TotalItemPrice + item_price>
</cfoutput>

<cfoutput>#TotalItemPrice#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: No need to loop over the query, using CF, you can do this in one line of code: <cfset TotalItemPrice = arraySum(myQry["item_price"]) />

Comment: Correct but arraySum cannot use in CF4.5

Comment: I don't see where CF 4.5 was a requirement. If version is not mentioned, I think its a safe assumption that they are using a version newer than one released 13 years ago.

Comment: then why would you bring up that my example above would not work with ColdFusion 4.5?

Comment: If you're still on CF 4.5, there are bigger issues than needing to sum a column of data. That said, I agree with both of Scott's above answers. This should be done in the database, but it would depend on what you needed to return from your query. If you needed the item_name and the item_price (or any other data from that query), the arraySum() function would probably be easiest and cleanest.